# Internet Explorer causes stack overflow

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, stack-overflow

I have a web application build on c# and ExtJS. While using Chrome/Firefox the app behaves as desired, but while using Internet Explorer, while using the scroll in certain tabs, the app crashes with an **Internet Explorer has stopped working** popup.

Using Visual Studio to debug this error I get this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x5A85605F (mshtml.dll) in iexplore.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x072C2FE8).

Also this error is reproducible only on the published version of the app, while running it in debug mode from visual studio no error appears.

If anyone could give me any tips from where to start, or what to look for, I would really appreciate it. I tried to search for this problem, but I could find nothing (this is not related to the crash when opening the Developer tools, as I can open it without any problems, though it doesn't help as no errors or warnings are rendered in console).

This issue is reproducible on multiple computers with Windows 10 using last version of IE 11.

Comment: I think if you report this to here https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/ they will take care of it :)

Comment: does it work in edge?

Comment: @ magicandre1981 yes, it does, only browser where it reproduces is IE